# Latitude and Longitude from Sql server 2014

Tags: android, google-maps

I created android app that shows map and the path between two points. works well.
Now I want to add 100 markers to show the way with latitude and longitude stored in SQL Server 2014 because the way I use to add the marker makes my code too large that why I want to add the marker with the latitude and longitude stored in SQL server 2014.

i don't know if the problem is on my code or do way i add the data in to database.
When i run the application the markers don't show
this is what i did so far

This is how i connect with Sql server

```
public class ConnectionClass {

    String ip = "UnitelTest.mssql.somee.com";
    String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String db = "UnitelTest";
    String un = "Eudes_SQLLogin_1";
    String password = "gj332zo1xq";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(classs);
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                    + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                    + password + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

I create  a list os thinks that i want from database:

```
public class Location {


    private String latlong_ID, latlong_nome;
    private Double latlong_Lat, latlong_Long;


    public Location(String latlong_ID, String latlong_nome,Double latlong_Lat,Double latlong_Long) {
        this.latlong_ID = latlong_ID;
        this.latlong_nome = latlong_nome;
        this.latlong_Lat = latlong_Lat;
        this.latlong_Long = latlong_Long;

    }

    public String getLatlong_ID() {
        return latlong_ID;
    }

    public void setLatlong_ID(String latlong_ID) {
        this.latlong_ID = latlong_ID;
    }

    public String getLatlong_nome() {
        return latlong_nome;
    }

    public void setLatlong_nome(String latlong_nome) {
        this.latlong_nome = latlong_nome;
    }

    public Double getLatlong_Lat() {
        return latlong_Lat;
    }

    public void setLatlong_Lat(Double latlong_Lat) {
        this.latlong_Lat = latlong_Lat;
    }

    public Double getLatlong_Long() {
        return latlong_Long;
    }

    public void setLatlong_Long(Double latlong_Long) {
        this.latlong_Long = latlong_Long;
    }
}
```

This is how i add lat and long from Sql server to my array:

```
public class LocationLatLong extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String z = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            for(int i = 0 ; i < location.size() ; i++ ) {

              //  createMarker(location.get(i).get,location.get(i).getLatlong_Long(),location.get(i).getLatlong_nome());

                createMarker(location.get(i).getLatlong_Lat(), location.get(i).getLatlong_Long());
            }
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                } else {
                    String query = "select * from LojaLocation";
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


                    while (rs.next()) {

                        String LatLongID = rs.getString("Id");
                        String LatLongnome = rs.getString("Nome");
                        String LatLongLat = rs.getString("Latitude");
                        String LatLongLong = rs.getString("Longitudi");

                        Double LatLong_Lat1 = Double.parseDouble(LatLongLat);
                        Double LatLong_Long1 = Double.parseDouble(LatLongLong);

                      //  LatLng position = new LatLng(LatLong_Lat1, LatLong_Long1);




                        Location p = new Location(LatLongID, LatLongnome, LatLong_Lat1,LatLong_Long1 );

                        location.add(p);

                    }



                    z = "Success";
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                z = "Error retrieving data from table";

            }
            return z;
        }

    }
```

And this is how i create my markers :

```
protected void createMarker(Double latitude, Double longitude, String title) {

        LatLng latLong = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLong)
                .title(title)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_marker)));

    }
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Don't store database credentials on a device, they can be easily extracted from the app. Common practice is to create a small web interface to interact with a database via HTTP requests.

Comment: Please provide some more info. Did you check if the markers are correctly stored on the database? Did you check if they are correctly loaded in the array? Does the loop execute 100 the right amount of times?

Comment: The loop works fine. This is my problem. i dont know if the problem is on my code or do way im storing the lat and long in Server

Comment: in my Database i Stored the name, lat and long of the marker as a varchar

Comment: Could you please help me